# Netbeans does not show browser window after successfull deployment of web application on Wildfly 15

Tags: java, netbeans, wildfly

I did update from wildfly 10.1 to wildlfy 15 and since then, when I start my applicaion, it gets deployed on the server, but browser does not show up automatically, no matter if I start it in debug or run mode. I saw same behavior on colleague computer. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Which version of Netbeans ? Also is a browser propeerly defined in Netbeans

Comment: [1] Select your project, right-click and select **Properties** from the context menu. [2] From the **Categories** list, select **Run**. [3] Check that the **Browser** field has an appropriate selection. [4] Ensure that **Display Browser on Run** is checked. [5] If the problem persists, what happens if you manually open the browser, and then submit the URL for your application - does that work?

Comment: These parametrs are all set. When I submit the URL manually, the server is running and serving right content, the only problem is with invoking the browser from Netbeans and the problem is only with wildfly 15. On wildfly 10, everything works as expected. This behavior was seen with Netbeans 8.2 and also on 11.2.

Comment: [1] Is this issue related to your [other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59303601/2985643) with NetBeans/Wildfly communication that you seem to have resolved? [2] Unrelated, but just FYI, if you are sending a comment to a specific user about your question, you should prefix your comment with an @ followed by their user ID (e.g. `@skomisa`). Otherwise your target gets no notification of your comment.

Comment: @skomisa This issue unfortunatily wasn´t solved by the solution of a problem you linked.