# Netbeans does not know that Wildfly already started

Tags: netbeans, wildfly

I´m using netbeans 11.2 with wildfly 15 application server. When i try to run my test applicaiton, after deployment I get this error:

```
WildFly Application Server Start Failed. HTTP Connector port 8080 is already in use.
```

The problem is, that when I hit the Run button, server starts, then application is deployed and then Netbeans tries to strat the server again, not knowing that it has already started.
It can be seen in the Run output:

```
Deploying on WildFly Application Server
profile mode: false
debug mode: false
force redeploy: true
Starting WildFly Application Server
WildFly Application Server Started
Distributing D:\BIOS\iRegPg\iRegPriv\target\iRegPrivPG-TEST_3.1.4.war
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
cd D:\BIOS\iRegPg\iRegPriv; JAVA_HOME=C:\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_231 cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-11.2\\netbeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dnetbeans.deploy=true -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-11.2\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -PIREG_TEST package\""
Scanning for projects...

Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for cz.bios.ireg:iRegPrivPG:war:TEST_3.1.4
'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ cz.bios.ireg:iRegPrivPG:${version.prefix}_3.1.4, D:\BIOS\iRegPg\iRegPriv\pom.xml, line 7, column 14

It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.


------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building iRegPrivPG TEST_3.1.4
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:copy (default) @ iRegPrivPG ---

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ iRegPrivPG ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 0 resource

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ iRegPrivPG ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ iRegPrivPG ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\BIOS\iRegPg\iRegPriv\src\test\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ iRegPrivPG ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ iRegPrivPG ---

--- maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) @ iRegPrivPG ---
Packaging webapp
Assembling webapp [iRegPrivPG] in [D:\BIOS\iRegPg\iRegPriv\target\iRegPrivPG-TEST_3.1.4]
Processing war project
Copying webapp webResources [D:\BIOS\iRegPg\iRegPriv/src/main/webapp] to [D:\BIOS\iRegPg\iRegPriv\target\iRegPrivPG-TEST_3.1.4]
Copying webapp resources [D:\BIOS\iRegPg\iRegPriv\src\main\webapp]
Webapp assembled in [344 msecs]
Building war: D:\BIOS\iRegPg\iRegPriv\target\iRegPrivPG-TEST_3.1.4.war
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.052 s
Finished at: 2019-12-12T12:23:44+01:00
Final Memory: 14M/251M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Deploying on WildFly Application Server
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Starting WildFly Application Server
WildFly Application Server Start Failed. HTTP Connector port 8080 is already in use.
```

IDE log:

```
java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0023: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:130)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager$EstablishingConnection.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:259)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementClientChannelStrategy$Establishing.getChannel(ManagementClientChannelStrategy.java:167)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:146)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$1.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:135)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:110)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:263)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:168)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:147)
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:75)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.ide.commands.WildflyClient.executeOnModelNode(WildflyClient.java:267)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.ide.commands.WildflyClient.undeploy(WildflyClient.java:529)
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.ide.commands.WildflyClient.undeploy(WildflyClient.java:535)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.ide.commands.WildflyClient.deploy(WildflyClient.java:547)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.javaee.wildfly.WildflyDeploymentManager.distribute(WildflyDeploymentManager.java:190)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.deploy(TargetServer.java:684)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:221)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.execution.DeploymentHelper.perform(DeploymentHelper.java:185)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.execution.CoSAlternativeExecutorImpl.execute(CoSAlternativeExecutorImpl.java:67)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.cos.CoSAlternativeExecutor.execute(CoSAlternativeExecutor.java:64)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.cos.CosChecker.checkRunMainClass(CosChecker.java:184)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.cos.CosChecker.checkRunConfig(CosChecker.java:138)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:213)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:128)
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer]: Cannot incrementally deploy to more than one target
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment]
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:234)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.execution.DeploymentHelper.perform(DeploymentHelper.java:185)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.execution.CoSAlternativeExecutorImpl.execute(CoSAlternativeExecutorImpl.java:67)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.cos.CoSAlternativeExecutor.execute(CoSAlternativeExecutor.java:64)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.cos.CosChecker.checkRunMainClass(CosChecker.java:184)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.cos.CosChecker.checkRunConfig(CosChecker.java:138)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:213)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:128)
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment]
org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerException: WildFly Application Server (15 - OLD) Start Failed. HTTP Connector port 8080 is already in use.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerInstance._startDebug(ServerInstance.java:1477)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerInstance.startTarget(ServerInstance.java:1382)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerInstance.startDebug(ServerInstance.java:1095)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.startTargets(TargetServer.java:514)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:190)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.execution.DeploymentHelper.perform(DeploymentHelper.java:185)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.execution.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:70)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:303)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:128)
WARN [org.xnio.future]: XNIO001003: Running IoFuture notifier org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionProvider$6@292032de failed
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Endpoint is not open
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.executorUntick(EndpointImpl.java:374)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor.execute(EndpointImpl.java:945)
    at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture.runNotifier(AbstractIoFuture.java:693)
    at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture$NotifierState.doNotify(AbstractIoFuture.java:267)
    at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture$NotifierState.notifyCancelled(AbstractIoFuture.java:258)
    at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture$CancelRequestedState.notifyCancelled(AbstractIoFuture.java:369)
    at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture.setCancelled(AbstractIoFuture.java:643)
    at org.xnio.FutureResult.setCancelled(FutureResult.java:98)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionProvider$6.handleCancelled(RemoteConnectionProvider.java:252)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionProvider$6.handleCancelled(RemoteConnectionProvider.java:250)
    at org.xnio.IoFuture$HandlingNotifier.notify(IoFuture.java:204)
[catch] at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture$NotifierRunnable.run(AbstractIoFuture.java:720)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.safeRun(WorkerThread.java:612)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:479)
```

Right now I have no idea, how to solve this.

Comment: I had the same problem with netbeans 10, which was solved by using nightly build version. Is it possible, that even it was solved in nightly version with NB 10, its still an issue in 11.2?

Comment: [1] Wildfly 18 is working fine for me on NetBeans11.2. Is it possible to upgrade to the latest Wildfly release? [2] As a possible workaround, instead of selecting **Run** from the context menu, try first selecting **Deploy**, and if that works then select **Run**. Does that work, or do you still get the same _"port 8080 is already in use"_ error? [3] Is anything relevant being written to the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) when you try to run your application and get the error?

Comment: [1] Upgrade is not possible right now. [2] I don't understand, deploy is not in the context menu. If you mean mvn deploy, I would need to have distribution management set in my pom.xml and i don't understand how that would help. [3] I have updated the question and envolved IDE log, some wierd stuff is there, really.

Comment: From the IDE log it can be seen, that netbeans is trying to communicate on port 9999. After adding management-native interface to standalone.xml it started working. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to this issue was adding native-management interface to wildfly configuration file like this:

```
    <management-interfaces>
        <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
        </native-interface>
        <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <http-upgrade enabled="true"/>
            <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
        </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
```

and than

```
<socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use below command from command prompt: It will kill port 8080

for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":8080" ^| find "LISTENING"') do taskkill /f /pid %a